# Best way to combine datetime in pandas dataframe when times are close

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What is the best way to combine times together if they are very close (within 5 seconds).

```
                   start                 end   delta
0    2016-01-01 08:00:01 2016-01-01 08:07:53   472.0
1    2016-01-01 08:07:54 2016-01-01 08:09:23    89.0
2    2016-01-01 08:09:24 2016-01-01 08:32:51  1407.0
3    2016-01-01 08:38:56 2016-01-01 08:38:58     2.0
4    2016-01-01 08:39:00 2016-01-01 08:58:06  1146.0
5    2016-01-01 09:07:26 2016-01-01 09:07:27     1.0
6    2016-01-01 09:07:31 2016-01-01 09:07:33     2.0
7    2016-01-01 09:07:35 2016-01-01 09:11:28   233.0
```

becomes

```
                   start                 end   delta
0    2016-01-01 08:00:01 2016-01-01 08:07:53   472.0
1    2016-01-01 08:07:54 2016-01-01 08:32:51  1496.0
2    2016-01-01 08:38:56 2016-01-01 08:58:06  1148.0
3    2016-01-01 09:07:26 2016-01-01 09:11:28   236.0
```

Comment: can you explain why the first two rows were not combined?

Comment: this is how the data was extracted from a set -- no computation was performed prior to this.

Comment: I mean why it wasn't combined in your desired data set? [`08:07:53` - `08:07:54`] - is within 5 secinds

Comment: does it matter? this is the set I got.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
timediff = df.start.diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
pd.DataFrame(
    {'start': df[(timediff>5) | (timediff.isnull())].start.tolist(),
    'end': df[(timediff.shift(-1)>5) |  (timediff.shift(-1).isnull())].end.tolist()}
    )
```

This will give you start and end  columns. Then you can take the delta.